# My granddaughter's Facebook account has been deleted

Tags: facebook

My granddaughter's Facebook account has been deleted. She is of age. There are plenty who is not, but she is. We know who reported her due to that person being mad with my granddaughter. Facebook is how she communicates with us and the bottom line is she is of age. I can send you a list of the ones who are not tho. I would appreciate you telling me what to do, because this is unfair.

Comment: Please note that this site is not Facebook support. It's a Q&A site where volunteers offer solutions to problems using web applications. You certainly need to get in touch with Facebook directly.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook usually sends an email to the ones who get their accounts disabled, with information about when and why they decided to disable it. If you disagree with the reason why the profile was disabled, I think you can send them an email explaining why do you think the profile doesn't need to be disabled. Keep in mind that they don't send emails to every disabled account, so there's a chance your granddaughter didn't get one.